# throwing error in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Wondering why my error inside the ajax call isn't being caught

```
if (!model_name){
    throw new Error (barcode + " invalid product");
  }


  $.post("php/ajax/check_ui_arguments.php", {barcode: barcode},
    function(message){
      if (message){
        var error = jQuery.parseJSON(message).msg;
        var errorstr = barcode +": "+ error;
        //alert(errorstr);
        throw new Error (errorstr);
      }
    });
```

the first exception gets thrown and caught but the second one will be thrown and uncaught in the console log.

Comment: AJAX is *asynchronous*.  The callback will run in the *future*, after your `try`/`catch` block is passed.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks